# Please give me an idea how to hide textboxes along grid in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, textbox

I got a requirement like taking input from the user through text box to fill grid whenever a dropdown list item "custom" is selected.
The textboxes "fromdate" to "Todate" are only need to appear on the screen whenever user selects "custom" item from dropdownlist. Please give me an idea how to hide these textboxes along grid in asp.net 4.0(Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: can u post ur requirement with snaps.

Comment: `from_Date` and `to_Date` are for search ?

Comment: Yes! I need to display From_date and to_date textboxes whenever user selects "custom" item in dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why don't you just do it, you already have the idea...

HTML:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <p>Your TextBoxes below...</p>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Custom"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddl.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("Custom"))
        pnl.Visible = true;
    else
        pnl.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to put textboxes inside a panel in asp.net,

```
<table><tr><td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Fromdate:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="fromdatetxt" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="103px" ></asp:TextBox></td>
           <td>
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Todate:"></asp:Label>
               <asp:TextBox ID="todatetxt" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="105px" ></asp:TextBox></td></tr></table>
</asp:Panel>
```

and write code in class file:

```
protected void atddroplist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
if (atddroplist.SelectedIndex == 5)
            {

                    datePanel.Visible = true;
}
```